# Rails serves old css file in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

In my application scss I had:

```css
.red {
  background-color: #F48585 !important;
}
```

Then I deleted these styling. Then I deployed my app to heroku,
so I did

```
git add -A
git commit -m "message"
git push heroku master
heroku run bundle 
heroku run rake db:setup
```

My app is deployed, styles from foundation framework etc work. But I still have my .red class styles defined. And also all new styles are ignored, it seems rails server old css file.
All of my style assets are precompiled into one file application.scss.

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: @Pavan, in production isn't assets precompiled automatically?

Comment: @Pavan, i have never run assets:precompile before, and didn't have any problems.

Comment: @Pavan, hmm it helped, interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you just forgot 1 step:**

git add -A

git commit -m "message"

> git push origin your-git-branch

git push heroku master

After last command heroku will automatically run bundle install and setup your project/app for running in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot to precompile your assets. Note that heroku will precompile the assets automatically only when there is not a `public/assets/manifest.yml` file in your repository, otherwise it will consider you're compiling your assets locally. See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally

In addition to that, in case you want to precompile the assets in deploy-time, together with removing your contents of the `public/assets` folder, you should have in mind that heroku will store the results of the precompilation as a temporary files, which would eventually be removed, so your production app cannot rely on those precompiled files.

So for your current situation you have mainly and high level two options:

1. Precompile your assets locally `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and commit the results to the repo. (faster right now)
2. Use a gem like https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync and precompile the assets in deploy time instead, but storing the results on a 3rd party cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, rake tmp:clear